# Jqplot dragable: constrain to one data point?

Tags: javascript, draggable, jqplot

I am working with JQplot and want people to be able to drag the last data point of a series up or down. The ConstrainTo allows me to limit the movement to up or down, but I can't find how to constrain it to only the last data point in the series being draggable. Now every data point in the series can be dragged. Is it possible to limit this to just the one data point?

Code snippet:

```
var GraphLabels=[];
GraphLabels[0] = {label:'Sales',renderer:$.jqplot.LineRenderer,color:'grey', 
lineWidth: 2,dragable:{constrainTo:'y'},isDragable: true};

function DrawGraphModel()
{
var Data = SeriesList[CurrentGraph.Series];
CurrentGraph.Plot = $.jqplot("chart", [Data.Sales, Data.FCast],
{
  stackSeries: false,
  series: GraphLabels,


  axesDefaults: {tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,tickOptions: {angle:00, fontSize:'10pt'}},
 axes: 
 {
  xaxis: {tickInterval:1, min:0, max:55, tickOptions: {angle: 90}},
  yaxis: {tickInterval: 25, min: 150, max: 450}
  },
  cursor: {show: true,followMouse: true},
  legend: 
  {
  renderer: $.jqplot.EnhancedLegendRenderer.min , 
  show: true,
  location: 'ne',
  placement: 'outside',
  marginRight: '50px'
  }
  });
 }
```

working online code: demo.judgmentalforecasting.com (people click a value on week 51, see a new series and drag their initial click up or down with this new information).